# How to check keystroke in WindowService

Tags: c#

is it possible to trace keystroke in  window service. I don't have idea about low-level keyboard hooks.
I want to insert some data into DB when i press some predefined keys using windowservice.

Comment: OP and up-voter need to famialarise themselves perhaps with [ask]

Comment: Windows services do not necessarily have an interactive user present. Capturing keypresses in a windows service makes little sense